# Solr cannot full-import cassandra DB

Tags: java, solr, cassandra

I have configured solr and cassandra. And when I'm trying to do this: `http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import` I'm getting an error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: the Cassandra implementation is always in auto-commit mode
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.setAutoCommit(CassandraConnection.java:382)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:172)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:127)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:366)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:38)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
        ... 12 more
```

How to fix that? Help me please :(

Answer (score 1):

**Solved.**
in `data-config.xml` file should type `autoCommit="true"`